# open()関数のエラー

Tags: python, eclipse

最近Pythonを独学で勉強し始めた者です。
まだ初心者とも呼べないほど未熟ですが質問失礼します。

Eclipseを利用しています。
open()関数で下記のようなコードを書きました。

```
open_file = open('point.txt')
raw_data = open_file.read()
open_file.close()
print(raw_data)
```

point.txtは同じフォルダ内にあり、Eclipseのアプリ内の実行では読み込んだ結果が表示されるのですがこれをコマンドプロンプトで実行すると

```
open_file = open('point.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'point.txt'
```

と表示されファイルが存在しないことになってしまいます。
Eclipseの設定がうまくできていないのでしょうか。

初歩的な質問ですみません。
ちなみにEclipseではPyDevを使っています。

Comment: 「point.txt は同じフォルダ内にあり」というのは、Python スクリプトと同じ階層にあるということでしょうか？　また、コマンドプロンプトから Python スクリプトを実行する際にはどのようにしたのか、コマンドプロンプトに打ち込んだコマンドを追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: アカウントが削除されてしまっているので、新しいコメントや編集ができないかもしれません。その場合、新しくアカウントを作って[「サポート」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から「その他」として運営チームにご報告頂ければ対処いたします。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

cdでカレントディレクトリを指定して実行してみると開けると思います。

Answer (score 0):

1行目を、次のようにフルパスを入れるなどで、プロンプトがどこであろうとうまくゆくと思います。
なお、「'r' または 'R' をプレフィックスは、バックスラッシュをリテラル文字として扱います」 そうです。 
open_file = open(r'D:\abc\efg\point.txt')